# How to do a JUnit assert on a message in a logger

Tags: java, logging, junit, assert

I have some code-under-test that calls on a Java logger to report its status.
In the JUnit test code, I would like to verify that the correct log entry was made in this logger. Something along the following lines:

```
methodUnderTest(bool x){
    if(x)
        logger.info("x happened")
}

@Test tester(){
    // perhaps setup a logger first.
    methodUnderTest(true);
    assertXXXXXX(loggedLevel(),Level.INFO);
}
```

I suppose that this could be done with a specially adapted logger (or handler, or formatter), but I would prefer to re-use a solution that already exists. (And, to be honest, it is not clear to me how to get at the logRecord from a logger, but suppose that that's possible.)

Comment: As the technology advanced in the meantime, you may consider accepting the JUnit 5 (Jupiter) `CapturedOutput` answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60527144/2886891, it is much more elegant.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Thanks a lot for these (surprisingly) quick and helpful answers; they put me on the right way for my solution.

The codebase were I want to use this, uses java.util.logging as its logger mechanism, and I don't feel at home enough in those codes to completely change that to log4j or to logger interfaces/facades.  But based on these suggestions, I 'hacked-up' a j.u.l.handler extension and that works as a treat.

A short summary follows. Extend `java.util.logging.Handler`:

```
class LogHandler extends Handler
{
    Level lastLevel = Level.FINEST;

    public Level  checkLevel() {
        return lastLevel;
    }    

    public void publish(LogRecord record) {
        lastLevel = record.getLevel();
    }

    public void close(){}
    public void flush(){}
}
```

Obviously, you can store as much as you like/want/need from the `LogRecord`, or push them all into a stack until you get an overflow.

In the preparation for the junit-test, you create a `java.util.logging.Logger` and add such a new `LogHandler` to it:

```
@Test tester() {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("my junit-test logger");
    LogHandler handler = new LogHandler();
    handler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
    logger.addHandler(handler);
    logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
```

The call to `setUseParentHandlers()` is to silence the normal handlers, so that (for this junit-test run) no unnecessary logging happens.  Do whatever your code-under-test needs to use this logger, run the test and assertEquality:

```
    libraryUnderTest.setLogger(logger);
    methodUnderTest(true);  // see original question.
    assertEquals("Log level as expected?", Level.INFO, handler.checkLevel() );
}
```

(Of course, you would move large part of this work into a `@Before` method and make assorted other improvements, but that would clutter this presentation.)

Comment: Anyone looking for ways in Spring boot please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/60527144/5930500

Comment: What if `libraryUnderTest.setLogger(logger);` isn't defined, which often happens with loggers as `private static final field`?

Answer (score 175):

I've needed this several times as well.  I've put together a small sample below, which you'd want to adjust to your needs.  Basically, you create your own `Appender` and add it to the logger you want.  If you'd want to collect everything, the root logger is a good place to start, but you can use a more specific if you'd like.  Don't forget to remove the Appender when you're done, otherwise you might create a memory leak.  Below I've done it within the test, but `setUp` or `@Before` and `tearDown` or `@After` might be better places, depending on your needs.

Also, the implementation below collects everything in a `List` in memory.  If you're logging a lot you might consider adding a filter to drop boring entries, or to write the log to a temporary file on disk (Hint: `LoggingEvent` is `Serializable`, so you should be able to just serialize the event objects, if your log message is.)

```
import org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

public class MyTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        final TestAppender appender = new TestAppender();
        final Logger logger = Logger.getRootLogger();
        logger.addAppender(appender);
        try {
            Logger.getLogger(MyTest.class).info("Test");
        }
        finally {
            logger.removeAppender(appender);
        }

        final List<LoggingEvent> log = appender.getLog();
        final LoggingEvent firstLogEntry = log.get(0);
        assertThat(firstLogEntry.getLevel(), is(Level.INFO));
        assertThat((String) firstLogEntry.getMessage(), is("Test"));
        assertThat(firstLogEntry.getLoggerName(), is("MyTest"));
    }
}

class TestAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {
    private final List<LoggingEvent> log = new ArrayList<LoggingEvent>();

    @Override
    public boolean requiresLayout() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void append(final LoggingEvent loggingEvent) {
        log.add(loggingEvent);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }

    public List<LoggingEvent> getLog() {
        return new ArrayList<LoggingEvent>(log);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great.  The only improvement I would make is to call `logger.getAllAppenders()`, then step through and call `appender.setThreshold(Level.OFF)` on each (and reset them when you're done!).  This makes sure that the "bad" messages you're trying to generate don't show up in the test logs and freak out the next developer.

Comment: In Log4j 2.x is slightly more convoluted as you need to create a plugin, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205093/how-to-create-a-custom-appender-in-log4j2

Comment: Thanks for this. But if you are using LogBack, you can use `ListAppender<ILoggingEvent>` instead of creating your own custom appender.

Comment: but this doesn't work for slf4j! do you know how can I change it to work with that as well?

Comment: @s.d If you cast the `Logger` to `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger` (the implementation class for the interface) you'll get access to `setAppender()/removeAppender()` again.

Comment: How likely is it, that some unit test will create a memory leak? After the unit tests ran, every resources are freed anyway or am I missing something?

Comment: How can we do the same in log4j2.x?

Answer (score 131):

Here is a simple and efficient Logback solution.
It doesn't require to add/create any new class.
It relies on [`ListAppender`](https://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/read/ListAppender.html) : a whitebox logback appender where log entries are added in a `public List` field that we could so use to make our assertions.

Here is a simple example.

Foo class :

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Foo {

    static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Foo .class);

    public void doThat() {
        LOGGER.info("start");
        //...
        LOGGER.info("finish");
    }
}
```

FooTest class :

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.core.read.ListAppender;

public class FooTest {

    @Test
    void doThat() throws Exception {
        // get Logback Logger 
        Logger fooLogger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Foo.class);

        // create and start a ListAppender
        ListAppender<ILoggingEvent> listAppender = new ListAppender<>();
        listAppender.start();

        // add the appender to the logger
        // addAppender is outdated now
        fooLogger.addAppender(listAppender);

        // call method under test
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.doThat();

        // JUnit assertions
        List<ILoggingEvent> logsList = listAppender.list;
        assertEquals("start", logsList.get(0)
                                      .getMessage());
        assertEquals(Level.INFO, logsList.get(0)
                                         .getLevel());

        assertEquals("finish", logsList.get(1)
                                       .getMessage());
        assertEquals(Level.INFO, logsList.get(1)
                                         .getLevel());
    }
}
```

JUnit assertions don't sound very adapted to assert some specific properties of the list elements.
Matcher/assertion libraries as AssertJ or Hamcrest appears better for that :

With AssertJ it would be :

```
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;

Assertions.assertThat(listAppender.list)
          .extracting(ILoggingEvent::getMessage, ILoggingEvent::getLevel)
          .containsExactly(Tuple.tuple("start", Level.INFO), Tuple.tuple("finish", Level.INFO));
```

Comment: Also, remember to not `mock` the class that is under test. You need to instantiate it with `new` operator

Comment: Seems kind of dumb that calling the `start()` method is necessary, but it is - don't forget to include that in your test or it won't work.

Comment: In my case `list` of appender was empty until I got root logger (not class logger):
`Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(org.slf4j.Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME)`

Comment: just in case if cannot find the `addAppender` method, you need to cast the fooLogger to an implementation class such as `ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger`. Then you have the `addAppender` method

Comment: One can actually use the `getFormattedMessage` which shows the final log message after applying all arguments, e.g. for `log.info("foo {}", "bar");` `logsList.get(0).getMessage()` will return `foo {}` while `logsList.get(0).getFormattedMessage()` gives `foo bar`

Comment: Plus note that `LoggerFactory.getLogger()` might return an `org.slf4j.helpers.SubstituteLogger` instance despite the usage of Logback while the logging is still initializing. You might need to poll for `ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger` up to a couple of milliseconds if you don't want flaky tests :)

Comment: hi @VasilenDonchev posted question here, maybe you can help answer, thank you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77924065/java-unit-test-error-class-org-slf4j-helpers-substitutelogger-cannot-be-cast-to

Answer (score 74):

For Junit 5 (Jupiter) Spring's [OutputCaptureExtension](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.x/api/org/springframework/boot/test/system/OutputCaptureExtension.html) is quite useful. It can be registered for an entire test class or for an individual test method via the `@ExtendWith` annotation. It's available since Spring Boot 2.2 and is available in the [spring-boot-test](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-test) artifact.

Example (taken from javadoc):

```
@ExtendWith(OutputCaptureExtension.class)
class MyTest {
    @Test
    void test(CapturedOutput output) {
        System.out.println("ok");
        assertThat(output).contains("ok");
        System.err.println("error");
    }

    @AfterEach
    void after(CapturedOutput output) {
        assertThat(output.getOut()).contains("ok");
        assertThat(output.getErr()).contains("error");
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe log statements are unlike `getOut()` or `getErr()`.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for (although the question is not spring boot related)!

Comment: @Ram It doesn't matter whether the logger is intercepted or the actual logging string, which is printed on the console, is intercepted. It works either way if the logger is configured to print to the console.

Comment: Wow! this is it. No need to use static mocking of the logger. Capture the actual output.

Comment: what is `assertThat` imported from here?

Comment: That is an [AssertJ](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core) assertion. Import would be `import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;`

Comment: Work for me. PS: replace the assert code like this: assertTrue(output.getOut().contains("xxx log"));

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work with debug level loggings. Is there a solution to capture debug loggings as well?

Comment: @mwalter If the debug level is configured to write to the console it will be captured as well.

Answer (score 22):

I also ran into the same challanged and ended up at this page. Although I am 11 years too late to answers the question, I thought maybe it could be still usefull for others. I found the answer of `davidxxx` with Logback and the ListAppander very usefull. I used the same configuration for multiple projects, however it was not so fun to copy/paste it and maintaining all the version when I needed to changes something. I thought it would be better to make a library out of it and contribute back to the community. It works with SLFJ4, Apache Log4j2, Java Util Logging, JBoss Logging, Google Flogger and with Lombok annotations. Please have a look here: [LogCaptor](https://github.com/Hakky54/log-captor) for detailed examples and how to add it to your project.

Example situation:

```
public class FooService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FooService.class);

    public void sayHello() {
        LOGGER.warn("Congratulations, you are pregnant!");
    }

}
```

Example unit test with usage of LogCaptor:

```
import nl.altindag.log.LogCaptor;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class FooServiceTest {

    @Test
    public void sayHelloShouldLogWarnMessage() {
        LogCaptor logCaptor = LogCaptor.forClass(FooService.class);

        FooService fooService = new FooService();
        fooService.sayHello();

        assertThat(logCaptor.getWarnLogs())
            .contains("Congratulations, you are pregnant!");
    }
}
```

I wasn't quite sure if I should post this here, because it could also be seen as a way to promote "my library" but I thought it could be helpful for developers who have the same challenges.

Comment: Quit easy to use and less boilerplate code! Great solution for me. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please add the imports?

Comment: @Readren just added it

Comment: Sadly, LogCaptor does not work for me. Just adding it to dependencies crashes the tests with various `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException` exceptions. I use Gradle, Groovy, Log4j2 and Apache Artemis libraries.

Comment: @Newerth if you can publish a small example on GitHub I can look into it what the issue is and provide a solution

Comment: @Hakan54 Apparently, it cannot cope with the `@Log4j2` annotation, which behaves similarly to `private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(App.class)`.

Comment: @Newerth hmm, strange as I have tested that use case see here in my test package https://github.com/Hakky54/log-captor/blob/9ed4aa5549fcf363771243d7a72df00257a574ef/src/test/java/nl/altindag/log/service/lombok/ServiceWithLombokAndLog4j2.java#26 The log4j2 annotation works and the passing unit test is the evidence... So I have the feeling that something else is causing the issue.

Answer (score 21):

Effectively you are testing a side-effect of a dependent class. For unit testing you need only to verify that

> `logger.info()`

was called with the correct parameter. Hence use a mocking framework to emulate logger and that will allow you to test your own class's behaviour.

It is an interesting trade-off: how much work is it to mock that dependent class? How much does it cost to set up a test harness including the dependent class and perform verification of the results of the dependency? Generally, if my "Unit" is highly algorithmic I prefer to invest time to isolate it using mocks.

Comment: How'd you mock a private static final field, which most loggers are defined? Powermockito? Have fun..

Comment: Stefano: That final field got initialised somehow, I've seen various approaches to injecting Mocks rather than the real thing. Probably requires that some level of design for testability in the first place. https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2011/11/testing-and-mocking-of-static-methods-in-java/

Comment: As Mehdi said, possibly using a suitable Handler may be enough,

Comment: @StefanoL: If a logger is defined with `private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(someString);`, you can still access it from unit tests with `Logger.getLogger(someString);`, modify it and add handlers (as in the accepted answer).

Comment: You might want to test a very specific settings of your `logback` settings. This is a pretty valid use case. We are sending our log to Kibana / Elastic and we need to ensure that our log is properly formatted and contains of the mandatory metadata.

Comment: @HonzaZidek If you have code that passes some formatting information to the log sub-system then ther are two separate things to Unit test: are you passing the expected format parameters to the logging unit, and does the logging unit produce the expecting result. If you are writing true Unit tests don't attempt to test both at the same time, don't look at log formats in your code's Unit test. It may be useful to have some Integration tests that do look at the combination, but be clear, these is not true, quick, repeatable, idependent Unit tests.

Comment: @djna "true Unit test" is a dogmatism :) In real life we often write a combination of unit tests and integration tests. And call them unit test. Because it's only a matter of what you call the "unit". It is just a point of view. It always depend on what the "unit" is in your case and what exactly you want to test. I was in projects where this dogmatic approach was forced and it was a hell! And the tests actually did not test much. A million mocks in the preparation, one small tested method called and a million on verifies. Thus the tests were just highly dependent on implementation!

Comment: @HonzaZidek yes, I agree, I don't want to impose Unit test purity where it makes more work, and is not helpful. I usually find myself favouring early integration testing. Here I want to challenge the OP need to test logging output - I am very doubtful that they need to do that, and I think an awareness of what Unit testing means is helpful. Rules are for guidance of the wise men and the obedience of fools!

Comment: @djna I wrote this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/429273/2886891 especially for your answer :)

Comment: @HonzaZidek I have edited, and I hope improved the answer ;-) Thanks.

Comment: @djna I have reverted my downvote and you improved your answer indeed :) However, after the introduction of JUnit5 `OutputCaptureExtension` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60527144/2886891) it is very easy. My own recent use-case was "verify that nothing was logged". Using `assertThat(output).isEmpty()` was even simpler than mocking the logger, especially if I *do* want the actual logger become visible for other *unexpected* exceptions.

Answer (score 19):

Another option is to mock Appender and verify if message was logged to this appender. Example for Log4j 1.2.x and mockito:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import org.apache.log4j.Appender;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;

public class MyTest {

    private final Appender appender = mock(Appender.class);
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getRootLogger();

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        logger.addAppender(appender);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // when
        Logger.getLogger(MyTest.class).info("Test");

        // then
        ArgumentCaptor<LoggingEvent> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(LoggingEvent.class);
        verify(appender).doAppend(argument.capture());
        assertEquals(Level.INFO, argument.getValue().getLevel());
        assertEquals("Test", argument.getValue().getMessage());
        assertEquals("MyTest", argument.getValue().getLoggerName());
    }

    @After
    public void cleanup() {
        logger.removeAppender(appender);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can we do the same in log4j2.x?

Comment: Nice and easy, I loved this solution. And it works with Logback too. You may want to add an AfterEach method where you call detachAppender() on the Logger

Answer (score 12):

For log4j2 the solution is slightly different because AppenderSkeleton is not available anymore. Additionally, using Mockito, or similar library to create an Appender with an ArgumentCaptor will not work if you're expecting multiple logging messages because the MutableLogEvent is reused over multiple log messages. The best solution I found for log4j2 is:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LogEvent;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractAppender;

private static MockedAppender mockedAppender;
private static Logger logger;

@Before
public void setup() {
    mockedAppender.message.clear();
}

/**
 * For some reason mvn test will not work if this is @Before, but in eclipse it works! As a
 * result, we use @BeforeClass.
 */
@BeforeClass
public static void setupClass() {
    mockedAppender = new MockedAppender();
    logger = (Logger)LogManager.getLogger(MatchingMetricsLogger.class);
    logger.addAppender(mockedAppender);
    logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
}

@AfterClass
public static void teardown() {
    logger.removeAppender(mockedAppender);
}

@Test
public void test() {
    // do something that causes logs
    for (String e : mockedAppender.message) {
        // add asserts for the log messages
    }
}

private static class MockedAppender extends AbstractAppender {

    List<String> message = new ArrayList<>();

    protected MockedAppender() {
        super("MockedAppender", null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void append(LogEvent event) {
        message.add(event.getMessage().getFormattedMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Mocking is an option here, although it would be hard, because loggers are generally private static final - so setting a mock logger wouldn't be a piece of cake, or would require modification of the class under test.

You can create a custom Appender (or whatever it's called), and register it - either via a test-only configuration file, or runtime (in a way, dependent on the logging framework).
And then you can get that appender (either statically, if declared in configuration file, or by its current reference, if you are plugging it runtime), and verify its contents.

Answer (score 11):

Inspired by @RonaldBlaschke's solution, I came up with this:

```
public class Log4JTester extends ExternalResource {
    TestAppender appender;

    @Override
    protected void before() {
        appender = new TestAppender();
        final Logger rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger();
        rootLogger.addAppender(appender);
    }

    @Override
    protected void after() {
        final Logger rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger();
        rootLogger.removeAppender(appender);
    }

    public void assertLogged(Matcher<String> matcher) {
        for(LoggingEvent event : appender.events) {
            if(matcher.matches(event.getMessage())) {
                return;
            }
        }
        fail("No event matches " + matcher);
    }

    private static class TestAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {

        List<LoggingEvent> events = new ArrayList<LoggingEvent>();

        @Override
        protected void append(LoggingEvent event) {
            events.add(event);
        }

        @Override
        public void close() {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean requiresLayout() {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

... which allows you to do:

```
@Rule public Log4JTester logTest = new Log4JTester();

@Test
public void testFoo() {
     user.setStatus(Status.PREMIUM);
     logTest.assertLogged(
        stringContains("Note added to account: premium customer"));
}
```

You could probably make it use hamcrest in a smarter way, but I've left it at this.

Answer (score 9):

Wow. I'm unsure why this was so hard. I found I was unable to use any of the code samples above because I was using log4j2 over slf4j. This is my solution:

```
public class SpecialLogServiceTest {

  @Mock
  private Appender appender;

  @Captor
  private ArgumentCaptor<LogEvent> captor;

  @InjectMocks
  private SpecialLogService specialLogService;

  private LoggerConfig loggerConfig;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    // prepare the appender so Log4j likes it
    when(appender.getName()).thenReturn("MockAppender");
    when(appender.isStarted()).thenReturn(true);
    when(appender.isStopped()).thenReturn(false);

    final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    final Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
    loggerConfig = config.getLoggerConfig("org.example.SpecialLogService");
    loggerConfig.addAppender(appender, AuditLogCRUDService.LEVEL_AUDIT, null);
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() {
    loggerConfig.removeAppender("MockAppender");
  }

  @Test
  public void writeLog_shouldCreateCorrectLogMessage() throws Exception {
    SpecialLog specialLog = new SpecialLogBuilder().build();
    String expectedLog = "this is my log message";

    specialLogService.writeLog(specialLog);

    verify(appender).append(captor.capture());
    assertThat(captor.getAllValues().size(), is(1));
    assertThat(captor.getAllValues().get(0).getMessage().toString(), is(expectedLog));
  }
}
```

Comment: This compiles, which is already better than other solutions, but the Appender does not seem to get used: `Wanted but not invoked: appender.append(<Capturing argument>);` even though the `log.info` method does definitely get called

Comment: @AdrienW I am glad it still compiles compiles (3 years later) but does it still work despite the warning?

Comment: Nope :/ since `appender.append` does not get called, I cannot capture the argument. Whithout the `verify` lines it runs, but it does nothing... Anyways, thanks for taking the time to respond 3 years later! I'll comment or answer here if I find a good solution

Comment: @AdrienW thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I'm no longer working on this project, so I can't check versions or see if it's still working for me. The only thing I can suggest is check that the loggerConfig is being set up correctly - maybe the package name is wrong? Good luck!

Comment: I got it to work with this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31836674/5018771 (I still don't know what exactly caused your solution not to work on my project but now I have one that does, thanks again for stopping by!)

Comment: @AdrienW thanks for sharing your solution, and I'm glad you got it working now!

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned from the others you could use a mocking framework. For this to make work you have to expose the logger in your class (although I would propably prefere to make it package private instead of creating a public setter).

The other solution is to create a fake logger by hand. You have to write the fake logger (more fixture code) but in this case I would prefer the enhanced readability of the tests against the saved code from the mocking framework.

I would do something like this:

```
class FakeLogger implements ILogger {
    public List<String> infos = new ArrayList<String>();
    public List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void info(String message) {
        infos.add(message);
    }

    public void error(String message) {
        errors.add(message);
    }
}

class TestMyClass {
    private MyClass myClass;        
    private FakeLogger logger;        

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        myClass = new MyClass();
        logger = new FakeLogger();
        myClass.logger = logger;
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyMethod() {
        myClass.myMethod(true);

        assertEquals(1, logger.infos.size());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is what i did for logback.

I created a TestAppender class:

```
public class TestAppender extends AppenderBase<ILoggingEvent> {

    private Stack<ILoggingEvent> events = new Stack<ILoggingEvent>();

    @Override
    protected void append(ILoggingEvent event) {
        events.add(event);
    }

    public void clear() {
        events.clear();
    }

    public ILoggingEvent getLastEvent() {
        return events.pop();
    }
}
```

Then in the parent of my testng unit test class I created a method:

```
protected TestAppender testAppender;

@BeforeClass
public void setupLogsForTesting() {
    Logger root = (Logger)LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
    testAppender = (TestAppender)root.getAppender("TEST");
    if (testAppender != null) {
        testAppender.clear();
    }
}
```

I have a logback-test.xml file defined in src/test/resources and I added a test appender:

```
<appender name="TEST" class="com.intuit.icn.TestAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

and added this appender to the root appender:

```
<root>
    <level value="error" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="TEST" />
</root>
```

Now in my test classes that extend from my parent test class I can get the appender and get the last message logged and verify the message, the level, the throwable.

```
ILoggingEvent lastEvent = testAppender.getLastEvent();
assertEquals(lastEvent.getMessage(), "...");
assertEquals(lastEvent.getLevel(), Level.WARN);
assertEquals(lastEvent.getThrowableProxy().getMessage(), "...");
```

Comment: I do not see where getAppender method is defined ?!?

Comment: getAppender is a method on a ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way

```
  @ExtendWith(OutputCaptureExtension.class)
  class MyTestClass { 
    
          @Test
          void my_test_method(CapturedOutput output) {
               assertThat(output).contains("my test log.");
          }
  }
```

Comment: it only logs all write operations to standard output (whole message logged by appender with corresponding patternlayout), there's no way to get the level of the log

Comment: Its pretty useful when you need to match the contents of the logger. It does my work.

Answer (score 4):

```
Here is the sample code to mock log, irrespective of the version used for junit or sping, springboot.

import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.core.Appender;
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.mockito.Matchers.argThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class MyTest {
  private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyTest.class);

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
    ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger root = (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
    final Appender mockAppender = mock(Appender.class);
    when(mockAppender.getName()).thenReturn("MOCK");
    root.addAppender(mockAppender);

    //... do whatever you need to trigger the log

    verify(mockAppender).doAppend(argThat(new ArgumentMatcher() {
      @Override
      public boolean matches(final Object argument) {
        return ((LoggingEvent)argument).getFormattedMessage().contains("Hey this is the message I want to see");
      }
    }));
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Line 'when(mockAppender.getName()).thenReturn("MOCK")' was not needed for me.

Answer (score 4):

Note that in Log4J 2.x, the public interface [`org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger.html) doesn't include the `setAppender()` and `removeAppender()` methods.

But if you're not doing anything too fancy, you should be able to cast it to the implementation class [`org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/Logger.html), which does expose those methods.

Here's an example with [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org) and [AssertJ](https://assertj.github.io/doc/):

```java
// Import the implementation class rather than the API interface
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger;
```

```java
// Cast logger to implementation class to get access to setAppender/removeAppender
Logger log = (Logger) LogManager.getLogger(MyClassUnderTest.class);

// Set up the mock appender, stubbing some methods Log4J needs internally
Appender appender = mock(Appender.class);
when(appender.getName()).thenReturn("Mock Appender");
when(appender.isStarted()).thenReturn(true);

log.addAppender(appender);
try {
    new MyClassUnderTest().doSomethingThatShouldLogAnError();
} finally {
    log.removeAppender(appender);
}

// Verify that we got an error with the expected message
ArgumentCaptor<LogEvent> logEventCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(LogEvent.class);
verify(appender).append(logEventCaptor.capture());
LogEvent logEvent = logEventCaptor.getValue();
assertThat(logEvent.getLevel()).isEqualTo(Level.ERROR);
assertThat(logEvent.getMessage().getFormattedMessage()).contains(expectedErrorMessage);
```

Answer (score 3):

As for me you can simplify your test by using `JUnit` with `Mockito`.
I propose following solution for it:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Appender;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.mockito.Captor;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.tuple;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyLogTest {
    private static final String FIRST_MESSAGE = "First message";
    private static final String SECOND_MESSAGE = "Second message";
    @Mock private Appender appender;
    @Captor private ArgumentCaptor<LoggingEvent> captor;
    @InjectMocks private MyLog;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        LogManager.getRootLogger().addAppender(appender);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        LogManager.getRootLogger().removeAppender(appender);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldLogExactlyTwoMessages() {
        testedClass.foo();

        then(appender).should(times(2)).doAppend(captor.capture());
        List<LoggingEvent> loggingEvents = captor.getAllValues();
        assertThat(loggingEvents).extracting("level", "renderedMessage").containsExactly(
                tuple(Level.INFO, FIRST_MESSAGE)
                tuple(Level.INFO, SECOND_MESSAGE)
        );
    }
}
```

That's why we have nice **flexibility** for tests with **different message quantity**

Comment: To do not repeat almost same code blocks want to add that almost 1to1 works for me for Log4j2. Just changing imports to "org.apache.logging.log4j.core", cast logger to "org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger", add
 `when(appender.isStarted()).thenReturn(true);
  when(appender.getName()).thenReturn("Test Appender");
`
and change LoggingEvent -> LogEvent

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to rely on hardcoded static global Loggers in your class implementation, you can provide a default logger in the default constructor and then use a specific constructor to set a reference to the provided logger.

```
class MyClassToTest {
    private final Logger logger;
    
    public MyClassToTest() {
      this(SomeStatic.logger);
    };
    
    MyClassToTest(Logger logger) {
      this.logger = logger;
    };
    
    public void someOperation() {
        logger.warn("warning message");
        // ...
    };
};

class MyClassToTestTest {
    
    @Test
    public warnCalled() {
        Logger loggerMock = mock(Logger.class);
        MyClassTest myClassToTest = new MyClassToTest(logger);
        myClassToTest.someOperation();
        verify(loggerMock).warn(anyString());
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this library https://github.com/Hakky54/log-captor

Include in your maven file the reference for the library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.hakky54</groupId>
    <artifactId>logcaptor</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

In java code test method you should include this:

```java
LogCaptor logCaptor = LogCaptor.forClass(MyClass.class);

 // do the test logic....

assertThat(logCaptor.getLogs()).contains("Some log to assert");
```

Comment: Assume you have this line in your service to test :
```java
public class YourService {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(YourService.class);
```
Also don't forget to add this dependencies for assertThat :

```java
        <!-- Logger unit test solution-->
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.19.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice and elegant way to approach this problem:
https://www.baeldung.com/junit-asserting-logs

Comment: The link to this site is not reachable anymore, if you still have info how it's done there, please edit your post so that others can benefit from it.

Comment: archived @ https://web.archive.org/web/20200927012213/https://www.baeldung.com/junit-asserting-logs

Answer (score 1):

What I have done if all I want to do is see that some string was logged (as opposed to verifying exact log statements which is just too brittle) is to redirect StdOut to a buffer, do a contains, then reset StdOut:

```
PrintStream original = System.out;
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
System.setOut(new PrintStream(buffer));

// Do something that logs

assertTrue(buffer.toString().contains(myMessage));
System.setOut(original);
```

Comment: I tried this with `java.util.logging` (though I used `System.setErr(new PrintStream(buffer));`, because it logs to stderr), but it does not work (the buffer stays empty). if I use `System.err.println("foo")` directly, it works, so I assume that the logging system keeps its own reference of the output stream, which it takes from `System.err`, so my call to  `System.setErr(..)` has no effect on the log output, as it happens after log system init.

Answer (score 1):

The API for Log4J2 is slightly different. Also you might be using its async appender. I created a latched appender for this:

```
    public static class LatchedAppender extends AbstractAppender implements AutoCloseable {

    private final List<LogEvent> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    private final CountDownLatch latch;
    private final LoggerConfig loggerConfig;

    public LatchedAppender(Class<?> classThatLogs, int expectedMessages) {
        this(classThatLogs, null, null, expectedMessages);
    }
    public LatchedAppender(Class<?> classThatLogs, Filter filter, Layout<? extends Serializable> layout, int expectedMessages) {
        super(classThatLogs.getName()+"."+"LatchedAppender", filter, layout);
        latch = new CountDownLatch(expectedMessages);
        final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
        final Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
        loggerConfig = config.getLoggerConfig(LogManager.getLogger(classThatLogs).getName());
        loggerConfig.addAppender(this, Level.ALL, ThresholdFilter.createFilter(Level.ALL, null, null));
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void append(LogEvent event) {
        messages.add(event);
        latch.countDown();
    }

    public List<LogEvent> awaitMessages() throws InterruptedException {
        assertTrue(latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        return messages;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        stop();
        loggerConfig.removeAppender(this.getName());
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
        try (LatchedAppender appender = new LatchedAppender(ClassUnderTest.class, 1)) {

        ClassUnderTest.methodThatLogs();
        List<LogEvent> events = appender.awaitMessages();
        assertEquals(1, events.size());
        //more assertions here

    }//appender removed
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea worth mentioning, although it's an older topic, is creating a CDI producer to inject your logger so the mocking becomes easy. (And it also gives the advantage of not having to declare the "whole logger statement" anymore, but that's off-topic)

Example:

Creating the logger to inject:

```
public class CdiResources {
  @Produces @LoggerType
  public Logger createLogger(final InjectionPoint ip) {
      return Logger.getLogger(ip.getMember().getDeclaringClass());
  }
}
```

The qualifier:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER})
public @interface LoggerType {
}
```

Using the logger in your production code:

```
public class ProductionCode {
    @Inject
    @LoggerType
    private Logger logger;

    public void logSomething() {
        logger.info("something");
    }
}
```

Testing the logger in your test code (giving an easyMock example):

```
@TestSubject
private ProductionCode productionCode = new ProductionCode();

@Mock
private Logger logger;

@Test
public void testTheLogger() {
   logger.info("something");
   replayAll();
   productionCode.logSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Jmockit (1.21) I was able to write this simple test. 
The test makes sure a specific ERROR message is called just once.

```
@Test
public void testErrorMessage() {
    final org.slf4j.Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger( MyConfig.class );

    new Expectations(logger) {{
        //make sure this error is happens just once.
        logger.error( "Something went wrong..." );
        times = 1;
    }};

    new MyTestObject().runSomethingWrong( "aaa" ); //SUT that eventually cause the error in the log.    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mocking the Appender can help capture the log lines.
Find sample on: http://clearqa.blogspot.co.uk/2016/12/test-log-lines.html

```
// Fully working test at: https://github.com/njaiswal/logLineTester/blob/master/src/test/java/com/nj/Utils/UtilsTest.java

@Test
public void testUtilsLog() throws InterruptedException {

    Logger utilsLogger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.nj.utils");

    final Appender mockAppender = mock(Appender.class);
    when(mockAppender.getName()).thenReturn("MOCK");
    utilsLogger.addAppender(mockAppender);

    final List<String> capturedLogs = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(3);

    //Capture logs
    doAnswer((invocation) -> {
        LoggingEvent loggingEvent = invocation.getArgumentAt(0, LoggingEvent.class);
        capturedLogs.add(loggingEvent.getFormattedMessage());
        latch.countDown();
        return null;
    }).when(mockAppender).doAppend(any());

    //Call method which will do logging to be tested
    Application.main(null);

    //Wait 5 seconds for latch to be true. That means 3 log lines were logged
    assertThat(latch.await(5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS), is(true));

    //Now assert the captured logs
    assertThat(capturedLogs, hasItem(containsString("One")));
    assertThat(capturedLogs, hasItem(containsString("Two")));
    assertThat(capturedLogs, hasItem(containsString("Three")));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code. I am using same code for my spring integration test where I am using log back for logging. Use method assertJobIsScheduled to assert the text printed in the log.

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.core.Appender;

private Logger rootLogger;
final Appender mockAppender = mock(Appender.class);

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    initMocks(this);
    when(mockAppender.getName()).thenReturn("MOCK");
    rootLogger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
    rootLogger.addAppender(mockAppender);
}

private void assertJobIsScheduled(final String matcherText) {
    verify(mockAppender).doAppend(argThat(new ArgumentMatcher() {
        @Override
        public boolean matches(final Object argument) {
            return ((LoggingEvent)argument).getFormattedMessage().contains(matcherText);
        }
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that you might be trying to test.

- When there is an event of interest to the operator of my program, does my program perform an appropriate logging operation, which can inform the operator of that event.
- When my program performs a logging operation, does the log message it produces have the correct text.

Those two things are actually different things, and so could be tested separately. However, testing the second (the text of messages) is so problematic, I recommend against doing it at all. A test of a message text will ultimately consist of checking that one text string (the expected message text) is the same as, or can be trivially derived from, the text string used in your logging code.

- Those tests do not test program logic at all, they only test that one resource (a string) is equivalent to another resource.
- The tests are fragile; even a minor tweak to the formatting of a log message breaks your tests.
- The tests are incompatible with internationalisation (translation) of your logging interface.The tests assume there is only one possible message text, and thus only one possible human language.

Note that having your program code (implementing some business logic, perhaps) directly calling the text logging interface is poor design (but unfortunately very commom). Code that is responsible for business logic is also deciding some logging policy and the text of log messages. It mixes business logic with user interface code (yes, log messages are part of your program's user interface). Those things should be separate.

I therefore recommend that business logic does not directly generate the text of log messages. Instead have it delegate to a logging object.

- The class of the logging object should provide a suitable internal API, which your business object can use to express the event that has occurred using objects of your domain model, not text strings.
- The implementation of your logging class is responsible for producing text representations of those domain objects, and rendering a suitable text description of the event, then forwarding that text message to the low level logging framework (such as JUL, log4j or slf4j).
- Your business logic is responsible only for calling the correct methods of the internal API of your logger class, passing the correct domain objects, to describe the actual events that occurred.
- Your concrete logging class `implements` an `interface`, which describes the internal API your business logic may use.
- Your class(es) that implements business logic and must perform logging has a reference to the logging object to delegate to. The class of the reference is the abstract `interface`.
- Use dependency injection to set up the reference to the logger.

You can then test that your business logic classes correctly tell the logging interface about events, by creating a mock logger, which implements the internal logging API, and using dependency injection in the set up phase of your test.

Like this:

```
 public class MyService {// The class we want to test
    private final MyLogger logger;

    public MyService(MyLogger logger) {
       this.logger = Objects.requireNonNull(logger);
    }

    public void performTwiddleOperation(Foo foo) {// The method we want to test
       ...// The business logic
       logger.performedTwiddleOperation(foo);
    }
 };

 public interface MyLogger {
    public void performedTwiddleOperation(Foo foo);
    ...
 };

 public final class MySl4jLogger: implements MyLogger {
    ...

    @Override
    public void performedTwiddleOperation(Foo foo) {
       logger.info("twiddled foo " + foo.getId());
    }
 }

 public final void MyProgram {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
       ...
       MyLogger logger = new MySl4jLogger(...);
       MyService service = new MyService(logger);
       startService(service);// or whatever you must do
       ...
    }
 }

 public class MyServiceTest {
    ...

    static final class MyMockLogger: implements MyLogger {
       private Food.id id;
       private int nCallsPerformedTwiddleOperation;
       ...

       @Override
       public void performedTwiddleOperation(Foo foo) {
          id = foo.id;
          ++nCallsPerformedTwiddleOperation;
       }

       void assertCalledPerformedTwiddleOperation(Foo.id id) {
          assertEquals("Called performedTwiddleOperation", 1, nCallsPerformedTwiddleOperation);
          assertEquals("Called performedTwiddleOperation with correct ID", id, this.id);
       }
    };

    @Test
    public void testPerformTwiddleOperation_1() {
       // Setup
       MyMockLogger logger = new MyMockLogger();
       MyService service = new MyService(logger);
       Foo.Id id = new Foo.Id(...);
       Foo foo = new Foo(id, 1);

       // Execute
       service.performedTwiddleOperation(foo);

       // Verify
       ...
       logger.assertCalledPerformedTwiddleOperation(id);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question for log4j see [how-can-i-test-with-junit-that-a-warning-was-logged-with-log4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15534239/1625740)

This is  newer and example with Log4j2 (tested with 2.11.2) and junit 5;

```
    package com.whatever.log;

    import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.*;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractAppender;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginAttribute;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginElement;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginFactory;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import static org.junit.Assert.*;

class TestLogger {

    private TestAppender testAppender;
    private LoggerConfig loggerConfig;
    private final Logger logger = (Logger)
            LogManager.getLogger(ClassUnderTest.class);

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Test Log Junit5 and log4j2")
    void test() {
        ClassUnderTest.logMessage();
        final LogEvent loggingEvent = testAppender.events.get(0);
        //asset equals 1 because log level is info, change it to debug and
        //the test will fail
        assertTrue(testAppender.events.size()==1,"Unexpected empty log");
        assertEquals(Level.INFO,loggingEvent.getLevel(),"Unexpected log level");
        assertEquals(loggingEvent.getMessage().toString()
                ,"Hello Test","Unexpected log message");
    }

    @BeforeEach
    private void setup() {
        testAppender = new TestAppender("TestAppender", null);

        final LoggerContext context = logger.getContext();
        final Configuration configuration = context.getConfiguration();

        loggerConfig = configuration.getLoggerConfig(logger.getName());
        loggerConfig.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        loggerConfig.addAppender(testAppender,Level.INFO,null);
        testAppender.start();
        context.updateLoggers();
    }

    @AfterEach
    void after(){
        testAppender.stop();
        loggerConfig.removeAppender("TestAppender");
        final LoggerContext context = logger.getContext();
        context.updateLoggers();
    }

    @Plugin( name = "TestAppender", category = Core.CATEGORY_NAME, elementType = Appender.ELEMENT_TYPE)
    static class TestAppender extends AbstractAppender {

        List<LogEvent> events = new ArrayList();

        protected TestAppender(String name, Filter filter) {
            super(name, filter, null);
        }

        @PluginFactory
        public static TestAppender createAppender(
                @PluginAttribute("name") String name,
                @PluginElement("Filter") Filter filter) {
            return new TestAppender(name, filter);
        }

        @Override
        public void append(LogEvent event) {
            events.add(event);
        }
    }

    static class ClassUnderTest {
        private static final Logger LOGGER =  (Logger) LogManager.getLogger(ClassUnderTest.class);
        public static void logMessage(){
            LOGGER.info("Hello Test");
            LOGGER.debug("Hello Test");
        }
    }
}
```

Using the following maven dependencies

```
 <dependency>
 <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>2.11.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried this and got an error inside the setup method on the line loggerConfig = configuration.getLoggerConfig(logger.getName());  The error is cannot access org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.LoggerContextShutdownEnabled class file for org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.LoggerContextShutdownEnabled not found

Comment: I reviewed the code and made some minor changes, but it worked for me. I suggest that you will check the dependencies and make sure that all imports are correct

Comment: Hello there Haim. I ended up implementing the logback solution...but I think you're right, in order to implement that one I had to clean an import I had made of another log4j version.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved the same issue as bellow:

```
Logger root = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(CSVTasklet.class); //CSVTasklet is my target class
    final Appender mockAppender = mock(Appender.class);
    root.addAppender(mockAppender); 

verify(mockAppender).doAppend(argThat((ArgumentMatcher) argument -> ((LoggingEvent) argument).getMessage().contains("No projects."))); // I checked "No projects." in the log
```

Answer (score 0):

Unit testing by adding an Appender does not really test the Logger's configuration. So, I think that it's one of the unique cases in which unit tests do not bring that much value, but an integration test brings a lot of value *(especially if your logging has some auditing purposes)*.

In order to create an integration test for it, let us suppose that you are running with a simple `ConsoleAppender` and want to test its output. Then, you should test how the message is written to its own `ByteArrayOutputStream` from `System.out`.

In that sense, I would do the following (I'm using JUnit 5):

```
public class Slf4jAuditLoggerTest {

    private final ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    @BeforeEach
    public void beforeEach() {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
    }
```

In that way, you are able to test its output by simply:

```
    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        // Given...
        // When...
        // Then
        assertTrue(outContent.toString().contains("[INFO] My formatted string from Logger"));
    }
```

If you do so, you will bring much more value to your project and will not need to using an in-memory implementation, create a new Appender, or whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Google's [Flogger](https://google.github.io/flogger/) logging API, here's how you can write a logging backend that can be used in tests:

```
import com.google.common.flogger.backend.LogData
import com.google.common.flogger.backend.LoggerBackend
import com.google.common.flogger.backend.system.BackendFactory
import java.lang.RuntimeException
import java.util.logging.Level
import java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE
import java.util.logging.Level.WARNING

/** Stores information about logs that occurred during test execution. */
class LogCollection {
  val messages = mutableListOf<String>()
}

class TestLoggingBackendFactory : BackendFactory() {
  /** Gets a singleton logging backend. */
  override fun create(p0: String?) = TestLoggingBackend
}

/** Flogger logging backend that listens to new logs during the test. */
object TestLoggingBackend : LoggerBackend() {
  val logs = LogCollection()

  override fun getLoggerName(): String = "TestLoggingBackend"

  override fun isLoggable(level: Level): Boolean = level in setOf(SEVERE, WARNING)

  override fun log(logData: LogData) {
    handleError(e = null, logData)
  }

  override fun handleError(e: RuntimeException?, logData: LogData) {
    logs.messages.add(logData.literalArgument.toString())
  }
}
```

Then somewhere you will need to set the system property

```
systemProperty(
  "flogger.backend_factory",
  "my.package.here.TestLoggingBackendFactory#getInstance"
)
```

and now you can access all of the logs that occur via `TestLoggingBackend.logs`.

I took this a step further and turned this into a JUnit rule with [Truth](https://github.com/google/truth) assertions, which you can see here: [`LoggingRule.kt`](https://github.com/hopskipnfall/EmuLinker-K/blob/master/emulinker/src/test/java/org/emulinker/testing/LoggingRule.kt)

Comment: Flogger is agnostic to the backend you pick for it, so you can either do as this answer suggests, or hook into the underlying logging system (JDK/Log4J2 etc.) to intercept logs.  I am actually working (spare time) on a backend agnostic log testing library (e.g. will work seamlessly with all common backends).

Comment: I just added a new answer which makes this one obsolete. The "flogger-testing" library (https://github.com/hagbard/flogger-testing) does much more than this and is much easier to set up.

Answer (score 0):

A new option for logs testing is my recently released "flogger-testing" library (https://github.com/hagbard/flogger-testing). Don't be fooled by the name as it can be used (with minor degradation in functionality) with Log4J and JDK logging. It supports both JUnit4 rules and JUnit5 extensions with the exact same assertion API for both.

It does not require arguably harmful practices, like forcing you to inject mocked loggers into code, and works perfectly with `static final` logger instances by intercepting the logs that are being emitted (so your tests are closer to testing what appears in log files).

Adding logging tests for a class is as easy as (JUnit5):

```java
  @RegisterExtension
  public final FloggerTestExtension logs = FloggerTestExtension.forClassUnderTest(INFO);
```

and the powerful fluent API is used like:

```java
@Test
public void testLoadData_missingFile() {
  // Do normal assertion about returned values.
  var result = ClassUnderTest.loadData(MISSING_FILE);
  assertThat(result).isEmpty();

  // Assert that we saw the expected warning ...
  LogEntry firstWarning = logs.assertLogs().withLevel(WARNING).getMatch(0);
  assertThat(firstWarning).hasMessageContaining("No such file", MISSING_FILE);
  assertThat(firstWarning).hasCause(IOException.class);
  // ... and assert that nothing seemed to go wrong before the first warning.
  logs.assertLogs(before(firstWarning)).never().haveCause();
}
```

It has lots of features not present in any other logs testing APIs mentioned in this thread:

- structured metadata testing
- setup common assertions for all tests to enforce logs policy
- override log levels in a single test (e.g. to ensure enabling finest logging causes no issues)
- bypassing rate limiting in tests (Flogger only)
- per-thread metadata to allow logs tests to reliably run in parallel (Flogger only)

Write more robust logging tests with a readable, powerful API.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using log4j2, the solution from https://www.dontpanicblog.co.uk/2018/04/29/test-log4j2-with-junit/  allowed me to assert messages were logged.

The solution goes like this:

- Define a log4j appender as an ExternalResource  rule

  ```
  public class LogAppenderResource extends ExternalResource {

  private static final String APPENDER_NAME = "log4jRuleAppender";

  /**
   * Logged messages contains level and message only.
   * This allows us to test that level and message are set.
   */
  private static final String PATTERN = "%-5level %msg";

  private Logger logger;
  private Appender appender;
  private final CharArrayWriter outContent = new CharArrayWriter();

  public LogAppenderResource(org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger logger) {
      this.logger = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger)logger;
  }

  @Override
  protected void before() {
      StringLayout layout = PatternLayout.newBuilder().withPattern(PATTERN).build();
      appender = WriterAppender.newBuilder()
              .setTarget(outContent)
              .setLayout(layout)
              .setName(APPENDER_NAME).build();
      appender.start();
      logger.addAppender(appender);
  }

  @Override
  protected void after() {
      logger.removeAppender(appender);
  }

  public String getOutput() {
      return outContent.toString();
      }
  }
  ```
- Define a test that use your ExternalResource rule

  ```
  public class LoggingTextListenerTest {

      @Rule public LogAppenderResource appender = new LogAppenderResource(LogManager.getLogger(LoggingTextListener.class)); 
      private LoggingTextListener listener = new LoggingTextListener(); //     Class under test

      @Test
      public void startedEvent_isLogged() {
      listener.started();
      assertThat(appender.getOutput(), containsString("started"));
      }
  }
  ```

Don't forget to have log4j2.xml as part of src/test/resources