# AppenderSkeleton (Log4j2)

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am trying to migrate a class that extends `org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton` from an old version of log4j to log4j 2. I was reading the JavaDoc for the class, and I read that,

> Appenders constructed using this are ignored in Log4j 2.

on the website for the class.

Does this mean, if I am using Log4j 2, I should extend this class? If yes, what should I use as an alternative? Would ConsoleAppender do the trick?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Appenders in Log4j 2 implement the Appender interface. Most Appenders will extend either [AbstractAppender](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/AbstractAppender.java), [AbstractOutputStreamAppender](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java), or [AbstractWriterAppender](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/AbstractWriterAppender.java). Log4j 2 uses Plugins, which means your appender will have to be annotated with @Plugin and defined as an Appender. Appenders also require a Builder annotated with @PluginBuilderFactory to create the Appender instance from its configuration. You can look at any of Log4j's Appenders, such as [FileAppender](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/FileAppender.java), for an example.

You will also notice that most of the Appenders use a Manager to perform most of the work. This is because Appenders are always recreated during a reconfiguration, which could lead to problems. The Managers are only recreated if attributes specific to that Manager are changed, otherwise the new Appender instance will reuse the previous Manager.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Plugins? That is something new to me. Are there any examples out there that look at?

Comment: Take a look at the file appender link in my answer and http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/plugins.html

Comment: Hello @rgoers, I have a custom appender that is implemented very much like the RollingFileAppender of log4j2 but it keeps restarting after each restart or reconfiguration. I have created a separate question about it, can you please take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71124877/how-to-retain-log4j2s-plugin-configs-after-server-restart-or-altering-xml-confi?noredirect=1#comment125744077_71124877

Answer (score 2):

The code supporting the accepted answer here is available in the [answer by David Lopez Carrasco to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31836674/5856262). This code should be supplemented with clearing the logs List in-between tests and test suites (otherwise the appender would hold messages from previous loggers).

Comment: You do now have the commenting privilege. If this is meant as a comment please delete it. If you think it can be an answer please [edit] according to [answer].