# SpringBoot log4j AppenderSkeleton The method append(LoggingEvent) must override or implement a supertype method

Tags: spring-boot, log4j

I'm trying to create a custom appender using log4j after looking at the given example -

**Link**:- [How to create my own Appender in log4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072389/how-to-create-my-own-appender-in-log4j)

I did as follows:-

```
import org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;

public class MyCustomAppender extends AppenderSkeleton
{


   private MailServiceImpl mail = new MailServiceImpl();

   @Override
   public void close() {            
   }

   @Override
   public boolean requiresLayout() {
       return false;
   }    
   @Override
   protected void append(LoggingEvent event) {

       mail.sendMail(event.toString());
   }
}
```

It gives me error because of the overridden methods - `The method append(LoggingEvent) of type MyCustomAppender must override or implement a supertype method`. I tried to search for solution but found none. And nobody seem to have faced the problem. Where am I going wrong? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a solution for Log4j2 but the stackoverflow page you are linking to is over 3 years old ( might be an older version of Log4j )

Looking at [javadoc of older version](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/AppenderSkeleton.html) it does show AppenderSkeleton could be used to override the appender() method   however   you mention you get a compile error

> The method append(LoggingEvent) of type MyCustomAppender must override
> or implement a supertype method

This is because there is no such method to override in Log4j2

Please provide version of what Log4j you are using, meanwhile have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59713891/appenderskeleton-log4j2) incase you are using Log4j2