# Mockito NullPointerException on mocked object

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, nullpointerexception, mockito

I have this classes:

```
public class MyClass(){

   private Logger logger;

   @Override
   public void prepare(Map map, TopologyContext topologyContext, OutputCollector outputCollector) {
     this.collector = outputCollector;
     logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
   }

    @Override
    public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
        if (TupleHelpers.isTickTuple(tuple)) {
            logger.info("Received tick tuple, triggering emit of current window counts");
        emitCurrentWindowAvgs();

        } else {

             ...
        }
    }
}
```

I want test it with Mockito in this way:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest {

 @Mock
 private Logger logger;

 @InjectMock
 private MyClass myclass;

 @Test
 public void myTest(){
      Tuple tickTuple = MockTupleHelpers.mockTickTuple();
      Myclass myclass = new MyClass();

    // when
    myClass.execute(tickTuple);

    // then
    // verifyZeroInteractions(collector);
    verify(collector).emit(any(Values.class));
}
```

However I obtain NullPointerException on `logger.info("...")`.

I also tried to add `doNothing().when(logger).info(anyString())` but the result does not change.

I searched it but in most cases the problem is the initialization of the mocked object.

Comment: what does MyClass do? it has no involement with the test, right?

Comment: @hunter i edit, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, I think you have two problems, one being:

```
logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IntermediateStatisticsBolt.class);
```

I assume this will overwrite your mock even if it is there (assuming, as I do not see when `prepare` is called).

The other is in your test, where you intantiate a new `MyClass`-object within the test instead of using the `myclass`-field which was populated by Mockito. It suffices to use `myclass` directly without an instantiation. Mockito and its `MockitoJunitRunner` will take care of its population.

Depending on your logging-framework you may also want to consider a logger-configuration which is dedicated to testing. For example, there exist at least [slf4j-test](http://projects.lidalia.org.uk/slf4j-test/) and [slf4jtesting](https://github.com/portingle/slf4jtesting) for slf4j where you can even assert your logging statements if you must.

If you want to keep your mocked logger and don't want to inject it from outside, you may want to use `PowerMockito`, or something like that. That way you can return it by mocking also your `LoggerFactory.getLogger`-call. Supplying a way to easily inject your logger from outside is probably nicer then using PowerMockito for it.

The benefit of using a logger-configuration dedicated to testing is clearly that you do not need to adapt your production code just to test that everything works fine and you can even spare some mocks (and their training) again ;-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you could make it easier for Mockito to **inject** that logger; like:

```
public class MyClass(){

  public MyClass() {
    this(LoggerFactory.getLogger(IntermediateStatisticsBolt.class));
  }

  MyClass(Logger logger) { this.logger = logger; }
```

That also makes it clearer how to pass in a logger for other testing purposes.

Beyond that, in that prepare method:

```
logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IntermediateStatisticsBolt.class);
```

is a **static** call.

Mockito can't mock those; you would have to look into PowerMock instead (when starting to test that method).

Comment: The problem isn't due to `LoggerFactory.getLogger` being a _static_ call... but rather that the static call pretty sure overwrites the already injected mock. Mockito can inject also mocks to private fields even if no accessor is there. Nonetheless, as also others have shown, supplying a way to easily inject the logger is still a good idea. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In your test, you define a mock `Logger`. However you don't do anything with it.

In your class under test, you create a `Logger` with `LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class)` -- the fact that you've created a mock logger elsewhere has no effect on this. Under all circumstances, including test, this class uses a real logger.

One way to get around this is to make the `Logger` injectable, for example with the constructor:

```
 public MyClass(Logger logger) {
      this.logger = logger;
 }
```

Another is to have a `setLogger(Logger logger)` method, and yet another is to allow your DI framework to perform field injection (getting into the realms of voodoo).

The simplest (most explicit) way to arrange this injection is to put it in an `@Before` method:

```
 @Mock private Logger mockLogger;

 private MyClass myObj; // class under test

 @Before setUp() {
      myObj = new MyClass(mockLogger);
 }
```

... but you can also use `@InjectMock`. One reason some people avoid `@InjectMock` is that it hides the exact issue you are experiencing. You expect it to inject your mock, but if the class has neither a suitable constructor parameter nor a setter, Mockito will silently continue without injecting anything.

There are other strategies for testing logging, which avoid using a mock logger: [How to do a JUnit assert on a message in a logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827677/how-to-do-a-junit-assert-on-a-message-in-a-logger)

Answer (score 1):

the problem is there in the test method,
you have defined a field in test class

```
  @InjectMock
  private MyClass myclass
```

But you doesn't use that, in the test method you have created a new instance of myClass

```
Myclass myclass = new MyClass();
```

`myClass` field will be hidden by `myClass` local variable, now the object that you created within the test method will contain the "`null`" for `logger`. no one is there to assigned that logger

Answer (score 0):

`IntermediateStatisticsBolt` isn't instantiated with your mocked logger, so you 'll get an NPE since it isn't otherwise instantiated in your class. You need to *inject* this logger (or the real variant in production)

e.g.

```
new IntermediateStatisticsBolt(logger); // i.e. a mock or real logger
```

(I would generally tend to instantiate loggers during class initialisation, and not bother testing them, to be honest)

Comment: Sometimes logging is a functional requirement and you really want to avoid regression (e.g. you have something monitoring your production logs for specific patterns) -- in which case they should be unit tested.

Comment: That *does* occur occasionally, I grant you. But relatively rarely in my experience