# How can I read maven logger output in junit test using java.util.logger?

Tags: java, logging, maven-3, java.util.logging

I enable maven logging by setting maven `quiet` property to false. Now I want to verify the output in a junit test. How can I get the this logger content ?

Comment: It sounds like you're using the tools in a wrong way. Why do you want to check the Maven output in a JUnit test?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a JUnit assert on a message in a logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827677/how-to-do-a-junit-assert-on-a-message-in-a-logger)