# How to write mockito test case for logging?

Tags: java, log4j, mockito

```
public void someMethod(Object obj) {
  ObjectMapper o = new ObjectMapper ();
  logger.info(o.writeValueAsString(obj));
}
```

I don't understand how to write test case for this.
I am using Apache log4j logger
And writing test case in mockito with spring boot

How to mock log when I have code like

```
class Someclass {

  Logger logger= LoggerFactory.getLogger(Someclass);
  //Some code and methods
}
```

Test class

```
class SomeclassTest{
  ...
  ...

  Logger logger;

  @Before {
  public void setup () {

  Mockito.when
    (LoggerFactory.getLoggers(Matchers.any(Class.class)))
   .thenReturn(logger);
  }
  ...
  ...
}
```

Comment: You inject a mock logger, you call your method, then you verify that info() has been called on your mock logger. But first, you fix the compilation errors, and you indent your code.

Comment: Correct but how can I mock the logger object. I have added a code in question for a reference

Comment: You won't be able to mock it with Mockito if you get it from a static method call thi way. Either use PowerMockito (can't help there), or inject it with Spring, or don' test your logs (do you really need to test that?)

Comment: Unfortunately yes... I have tried to mock it but I am not able to do it'. I have added the code which I try

Comment: You won't be able to mock it with Mockito if you get it from a static method call this way. Either use PowerMockito (can't help there), or inject it with Spring.

Comment: How can I inject it in spring?? Could you please explain or show some example if possible

Comment: You define a Logger as a spring bean, with a`@Bean`-annotated method of a configuration class, and you inject it like any other bean.

Comment: @JBNizet _"do you really need to test that?"_ <- asking the important questions :)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827677

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a JUnit assert on a message in a logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827677/how-to-do-a-junit-assert-on-a-message-in-a-logger)