# How can I unit test Java classes with private static final Logger field

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit5

I've been working on a web application that uses Java 17 in conjunction with Spring 5.3, JUnit 5.9 and Mockito 5.1.

Throughout the code base, I frequently see classes with a log field declared as `private static final`. These fields commonly appear in catch blocks as referenced below and I struggle finding ways to directly cover them in unit tests.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Yorkie {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Yorkie.class);

    private String favoriteToy = "Ball";

    private String fetchFavoriteToy() throws Exception {
      
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
            throw new Exception("Favorite toy not found!");
        }
        return favoriteToy;
    }

    private void bark() {
        try {
            String toy = fetchFavoriteToy();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(LoggingFacade.formatError("ERROR-Dog", null, null,
                    null, "Unable to bark: " + e.getMessage()));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Yorkie yorkie = new Yorkie();
        yorkie.bark();
    }
}
```

Is there a safe way of actually asserting anything about `LOGGER` strictly using JUnit and Mockito?

Comment: What exactly do you want to assert?

Comment: Anything related to the state of `LOGGER` which will enable me to validate that the line was executed. I'm under the impression this cannot be done in a deterministic manner due to tests being run in parallel and the field being shared between them.

Comment: See https://github.com/Hakky54/log-captor and a possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827677

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a JUnit assert on a message in a logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827677/how-to-do-a-junit-assert-on-a-message-in-a-logger)

Answer (score 0):

One workaround could be to use a custom appender class for logging events in order to collect and assert. So for example, if logback is used with slf4j, then:

```java
public class Appender extends AppenderBase<ILoggingEvent> {
    static List<ILoggingEvent> events = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void append(ILoggingEvent e) {
        events.add(e);
    }

    public static List<ILoggingEvent> getEvents() {
        return events;
    }

    public static void clear() {
        events.clear();
    }
}
```

Then for test cases custom appender could be used (configuration should be in the resources path of tests):

```xml
<configuration>
    <appender name="appender" class="org.your.package">
    </appender>
    <root level="trace">
        <appender-ref ref="appender"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

And in the test itself:

```java
  List<ILoggingEvent> l = Appender.getEvents()
  // assert
```

But there will be racing conditions accessing this static appender, which could be resolved as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a library that can do this: [junit-support](https://robtimus.github.io/junit-support/extension/test-logger.html). The `@TestLogger` annotation allows you to inject a logger context, which can then be used to configure appenders, log levels, etc. At the end of the test all logging will be reset, which makes it really easy to create standalone tests.

The only thing you need to provide for yourself is an actual logging implementation (or in this case, SLF4J bridge): one of java.util.logging, Log4J 2, logback or reload4j.

An example for reload4j; the only real difference for the other implementations is the context class to use:

```
@Test
void testLogging(@TestLogger.ForClass(MyClass.class) Reload4jLoggerContext loggerContext) {
    Appender appender = mock(Appender.class);
    loggerContext
            .setLevel(Level.INFO)
            .useParentAppenders(false)
            .setAppender(appender);

    // perform calls that trigger the logger

    ArgumentCaptor<LoggingEvent> eventCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(LoggingEvent.class);
    verify(appender, atLeastOnce()).doAppend(eventCaptor.capture());
    List<LoggingEvent> events = eventCaptor.getAllValues();
    // perform assertions on events
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you remove `final`, you can use reflection to inject a mock Logger:

```
private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Yorkie.class);
```

Then in your test:

```
Logger mockLogger = mock(Logger.class);
Yorkie.class.getDeclaredField("LOGGER");
loggerField.setAccessible(true); // undo "private"
loggerField.set(null, mockLogger);
```

Then you can assert how logger is being called:

```
verify(mockLogger). error(anyString());
```

---

Before Java 12, you could use reflection to alter a `final` field, but not after. There's no practical advantage to making the field non-final - it's mainly a style thing. Making your code testable trumps style.