# Why Log info is not printing in IDE console while running JUNIT?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I am using IntelliJ to run Junit. I have below java method and it has LOGGER(org.slf4j.Logge) details

```
public String getName(){
        LOGGER.info("getName method is called....");
        return name;
}
```

I have have junit for this method,

```
@Test
    public void testGetName() {
        String expected = "hello";
        assertEquals(expected, model.getName());
}
```

The test method works fine as expected but I want to see LOG details in the console but when I run the junit it just executes and does not  print the log message "getName method is called....". Is there any setting I should do to make it work ?

Comment: JUnit redirects stdout, so just use the debugger if you want to see what's going on in the code; if you want to assert that logging is happening (and be warned, such tests are brittle), then see - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827677/how-to-do-a-junit-assert-on-a-message-in-a-logger

Comment: thanks. yeah, i am currently using running the test classes using debug mode. But still I want to see all log detail within IDE.It is basically for local development

Answer (score 0):

You say you're expecting to see the message in Console but you can't. The code you provide is very brief. The main issue here probably doesn't hide in the code you provide but rather in the logging (appender) configuration, that is missing in the question. So, I just expect it's missing from your setup and thus you can't see the log message in Console.

SLF4J itself is an abstraction and doesn't provide a concrete logging implementation; it relies on a binding to a specific logging framework - like Log4j or others. Lets say you choose Log4j, then, you just need to configure an appender, like e.g.

```
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

and save this XML to a proper location with proper naming like log4j2.xml - or else, but ensure Log4j knows where the configuration is located. This depends on your setup. It shouldn't be hard to find more details on this.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I created a log4j2.xml and placed it in my resource folder. But I am not sure how to ask Log4j to use log4j2.xml. I am using a maven project, should I do any config in POM.xml? any Intellij settings? Can you please help me to set this? Please let me know if I can refer to any doc.

Comment: Hard to believe, but it should be possible to find it in Apache docs :), e.g. https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html. If file is on classpath, log4j2 shall find it on its own, otherwise you can define also by argument -Dlog4j.configurationFile. Should be possibe to find more info on these. Anyway, we don't even know if it's really Log4j2 log library that you actually use. Do you?

Comment: I am using org.slf4j.Logger package. let me check also if there is any doc. thanks

Comment: Slf4j is just a facade, you are expected to use some logging lib with it. It's like having a kitchen ... so you can go there and cook something. Oh wait, you dont have there any cooker yet. You need any cooker first. You need some logging lib.